# Android : Change SQLite DB on upgrade

Tags: android, sqlite, updates

I want to add a column to my existing database

However I'm imagining I'm in the scenario where people have already got a version of the code and database and I'm going to make the changes through a update on google play, therefore previous data cannot be lost

To create my database I used the following code;

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_calculation);
  db = openOrCreateDatabase("EJuiceData", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
  db.execSQL("create table if not exists Inventory(_id integer primary key autoincrement, NAME TEXT NOT NULL, AMOUNT TEXT, PRICE TEXT, AMOUNTLEFT TEXT, WEIGHT TEXT);");
....
```

I've looked around online and people are mentioning using the following command to update;

```
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
  if (newVersion > oldVersion) {
    db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE Recipe ADD COLUMN NOTES TEXT");
  }
}
```

However onUpgrade is commented out stating the it isn't being called, also no where in my code have I stated what version of the database it is or given a new version

Anyone know how I get around this issue?

Thanks

EDIT;

From looking at the answers I've decided to try do this the most efficient way and what's seen as the best practice

So I've created a new Java Class called MyDBHelper which has the following

```
package com.sjhdevelopment.shaunharrison.myejuiceapp;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class MyDBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

  public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "EJuiceData.db";
  public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;



  public MovieDatabaseHelper(Context context) {
      super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

  }

  public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
    database.execSQL("create table if not exists Recipe");
    .....

  }

  @Override
  public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase database, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    if (newVersion > oldVersion)
        database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE Recipe ADD COLUMN NOTES TEXT");
    onCreate(database);
  }

}
```

So far I have an error on MovieDatabaseHelper stating 'invalid method declared; return type required

Comment: Can you post the logs ? Which line is the error ? You also forgot the `@Override` before onCreate

Comment: There is no log as I haven't ran the code yet, there is a red line underneath `public MovieDatabaseHelper(Context context)`

Comment: replace MovieDatabaseHelper by the name of your class (MyDBHelper). This is the constructor !

Comment: That did work, I blame this on it being monday morning! thanks for that

Comment: So on a different form now i've put in the following `MyDBHelper helper = new MyDBHelper(getContext());` however `getContext` is causing an error 'can't resolve method 'getContext()''

Comment: You must call it from within an activity or a fragment. It should work from `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` (the one you used to create your database)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92031/discussion-between-sjharrison-and-maloubobola).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you using SQLiteOpenHelper ? If yes you must have a version you send to the super class from the constructor (see [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html))

Here is a code sample. The `onUpgrade` function will be called when the DATABASE_VERSION changes.

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "EJuiceData.db";

    public DatabaseHelper (Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
        database.execSQL("create table if not exists Inventory(_id integer primary key autoincrement, NAME TEXT NOT NULL, AMOUNT TEXT, PRICE TEXT, AMOUNTLEFT TEXT, WEIGHT TEXT);");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase database, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        if (newVersion > oldVersion) {
            db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE Recipe ADD COLUMN NOTES TEXT");
            onCreate(database);
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

now you can get access your database using

```
DatabaseHelper helper = new DatabaseHelper(getContext());
helper.getReadableDatabase().query(...);
//or
helper.getWritableDatabase().insert(...);
```

Comment: I'm not using a SQLiteOpenHelper, the create command is in the OnCreate of the first form that opens

Comment: You can create a private attribute called `verion` and manually upgrade your database if your version change. But this is better practice (and easier) to use the SQLiteOpenHelper. (See edit)

Comment: Hi @Maloubobola, I'm trying to use your answer to get this working 

I've copied your code into a new Java class however MovieDatabaseHelper is throwing an error stating that a return type is required

Comment: where is the error thrown ? Can you provide more details ?

Answer (score 2):

```
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    if (oldVersion < newVersion)
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS '" + TABLE_NAME + "'");
        onCreate(db);
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't answer my question, I have seen plenty of methods like this, which is why I've posted a question on here

Comment: You can add @Override above of oncreate()

Answer (score 1):

You can extend **SQLiteOpenHelper** like below code, and new your helper class with version param which db version you want to open.

If you open db with version 1, and next time you open db with version 2, the onUpgrade method will be called with param ordVersion = 1 and newVersion = 2, then you can do something to upgrade your db schema here.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class MyDBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "mydata.db";
    public static final int VERSION = 1;    
    private static SQLiteDatabase database;

    public MyDBHelper(Context context, String name, CursorFactory factory,
            int version) {
        super(context, name, factory, version);
    }

    public static SQLiteDatabase getDatabase(Context context) {
        if (database == null || !database.isOpen()) {
            database = new MyDBHelper(context, DATABASE_NAME, 
                    null, VERSION).getWritableDatabase();
        }

        return database;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        onCreate(db);
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, so would it be best for me to create a new Java class and use the code above in there? If so on my previous class I've been using `db = openOrCreateDatabase("EJuiceData", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);` to connect to the database, will I still be able to use that? thanks

Comment: You can change the code to db = new MyDBHelper(ActivityContext, "EJuiceData", null, DBVersionCode).getWritableDatabase();

Comment: or MyDBHelper.getDatabase(ActivityContext) and change "DATABASE_NAME" "VERSION" in MyDBHelper class